# Any plans for firebase to allow serverside socket connections from other languages e.g. Java?

Tags: firebase

I appreciate you have the full REST API which is great but I wondered if it would be possible in the future to have a socket conenction from Java to firebase similar to the node.js version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently provide clients for JS (both for the web and for Node.js) and a REST API. Our intention is to eventually provide full real-time libraries for all types of clients and server languages. We don't have a Java library currently in the works, but we do intend to build one when time allows it.

Comment: Thats great thanks - going to look at using node as maybe some form of middleman to the Java application server.  I know it seems strange but what I am really after I suppose is some form of headless client which can trigger other things.  What I will probably do is have node perform REST calls to the Java server, my only other alternative would have been to poll from the Java server.

Answer (score -1):

<del>You can use a [Java WebSockets Client](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) to connect to Firebase if you're unhappy with the REST API. Under the hood, this is what node.js (i.e. the [faye-websockets-node](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-node) library) is doing.</del>

Comment: This isn't actually true. We provide a full-fledged Node.js client with all of the features of the web client.

Comment: @AndrewLee Hm, I suppose I hadn't thought through the implications of the Firebase.js library from a Java environment :( For some reason I had it in mind that you could perform the same REST API calls via web sockets, which doesn't make a good deal of sense. I wonder what could be done via Rhino?

Comment: Rhino would be an interesting thought : ) The long-term plan is to make a native lib work here though.